# Best mechanism for access control to AWS / Cloud Resources for remote users

Tags: networking, vpn, cloud

We use Cloud solutions such as AWS and Azure, so frequently access EC2 instances, AWS Workspaces etc.

These cloud resources are only accessible to a static public IP address. So our employees use company VPN (setup through Fortigate Firewall) to access these cloud resources.

We have no physical servers or any other internal networks, so this firewall is essentially just for our VPN. Is there a better way to enforce access control for multiple users to cloud resources without having a physical firewall?